# Broadcast join to generate all pairs of tuples from same large RDD without duplicates

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For one large RDD with structure (key, value) I want to generate all tuples (key1, key2, value1, value2) where no duplicates or self-pairs should exist. Namely, (key1, key2, value1, value2) and (key2, key1, value2, value1) are considered duplicates.

In the SQL world one would perform something like

```
SELECT A.key, B.key 
FROM TABLE1 as A CROSS JOIN TABLE1 as B
WHERE A.key < B.key
```

But for my spark data set, a cross-join (cartesian) is too expensive to compute.

How could I generate all desired tuples by using a broadcast join and applying the condition that key1 > key2?

In terms of code, assume RDD set with elements of type (key, value):

```
val broadcastSet = spark.broadcast(set.collect().toMap)
val result = set.map { (k,v) => { **???** } }
```

where ***???*** is a way to iterate through all values in the broadcastSet and apply the order condition key1 > key2?

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: can you share sample input and expected output too? it would be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you want to emit more or less records than what exist in a set, you use `.flatMap()`. Something like this (untested code) should work:

```
val result = set.flatMap { (k1,v1) => {
  broadcastSet.value.flatMap { (k2,v2) => {
    if (k1 > k2) {
      Some(k1, k2, v1, v2)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }}
}}
```

This pattern, whether `.flatMap()` or `.map()`, is considered a "map-side join", and can be a powerful way to reduce shuffle overhead that will be filtered out later anyway.

Comment: I'm getting some unwanted tuples here for, I presume, the cases when the if condition is not satisfied. Can I have these not generated at all?

Comment: When the if condition is *not* satisfied, a `None` is emitted, which gets flattened out of the resulting dataset. Perhaps you need to add more conditions to filter unwanted tuples.